# The argument type 'void Function(GoogleMapController)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

my google maps controller is created in a separate dart called app_state.dart file that i import to the main dart file, so i am trying to use the same google maps controller in  the separate file in the main  but keep getting and error in the main file

this is the function im trying to call in the separate file

```
void toUserLocation(GoogleMapController controller){

  _mapController = controller;
_mapController.animateCamera(
      CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
        CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(37.4219999, -122.0862462), zoom: 20.0),
      ),
    );






}
```

And this is the onPressed action in the main dart file i am trying to usebut i am trying to use it thats giving me the error **The argument type 'void Function(GoogleMapController)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'**

```
Positioned(
        top: 100,
        right: 10,
         child: FloatingActionButton(onPressed:appState.toUserLocation),
         tooltip: "ad marker",
         backgroundColor:Colors.white,
         child: Icon(Icons.add_location, color:Colors.black,),
         ),
      )
```

Comment: The `controller` parameter to the function `toUserLocation` is missing in `onPressed:appState.toUserLocation`.